# A reader class misreading a txt (0false at the end of each string saved)

Tags: java, text, arraylist, reader

I've created a reader class that receives an ArrayList and starts reading a .txt to save each line in a new element of carreer (every time the reader finds a new line with text, it adds a new element to the ArrayList). It works because when I print the content of the ArrayList, the reader truly saves the content, but with a `0false` at the end.
This is what I did on my main class:

```
ArrayList<Carrera> clista = new ArrayList<Carrera>();
CarreraReader lectorCarrera = new CarreraReader();
lectorCarrera.leer(clista);
```

And this is the method in my reader class:

```
public void leer(ArrayList<Carrera> clista) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("thetext.txt"));

        while(s.hasNextLine())
        {
            Carrera cq = new Carrera();
            cq.setNombre(s.nextLine());
            clista.add(cq);
        }
```

So it saves a lot of strings indicating a college career, but in this way:
e.g:

```
Engineering0false
Art0false
Law0false
Agronomy0false
```

How can I prevent the reader from saving `0false` at the end of every string? Is there anything I did wrong? I tried this same reader in a single class project and It worked perfectly, no String had a `0false` at the end.

This is my Carrera class implementation:

```
package paquete;

public class Carrera {

    private String nombre;
    private int duracion;
    private String codigo;
    private boolean acreditado;

    public Carrera() {
        nombre="";
        duracion=0;
        codigo="";
        acreditado=false;
    }

    public Carrera(String nombre, int duracion, String codigo, boolean acreditado) {
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.duracion=duracion;
        this.codigo=codigo;
        this.acreditado=acreditado;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }


    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getDuracion() {
        return duracion;
    }

    public void setDuracion(int duracion) {
        this.duracion = duracion;
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public boolean isAcreditado() {
        return acreditado;
    }

    public void setAcreditado(boolean acreditado) {
        this.acreditado = acreditado;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return nombre;
    }
}
```

Here is how I print the content:

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<clista.size();i++){
System.out.println(clista.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Post `Carrera.setNombre(String)` please. And how you are determining the `String`(s) saved.

Comment: `public void setNombre(String nombre) {
this.nombre = nombre;
}`

Comment: Use a debugger to see what is happening to `cq` after this line executes `cq.setNombre(s.nextLine());`. If it is exactly what it should be, the issue is probably in your printing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use the String split method? You can pass as parameter the "0false" argument and save only the part you want.

```
while(s.hasNextLine())
    {
        Carrera cq = new Carrera();
        String name = s.nextLine());
        cq.setNombre(name.split("false0")[0]);
        clista.add(cq);
    }
```

Comment: that did work! thanks, but is this reliable for a professor when he looks over your project?